# What is the max verb length for Windows Shell?

Tags: shell, winapi

How long can a verb be for things like `GCS_VERBA` / `GCS_VERBW` used with `IContextMenu::GetCommandString()`.  It looks like they are kept short but for buffer allocation, what reasonable size should be used (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)?

TIA!!

Comment: It's not documented. An upper limit would probably be imposed by the maximum length of a registry key name, which is [255](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits), although that only applies to static verbs.

Comment: Sounds like a possible future article idea for Raymond Chen's blog :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jonathan Potter says in the comments, the verb limit is not documented but registry limits are.

However, I see in my old notes that the Windows shell used to do `TCHAR verb[128];` in certain places. This was 15+ years ago but there is no reason not to use those as your limits:

- When reading a verb into your own buffer, make sure it can contain >= 255 characters.
- When inventing your own verbs, make sure they are < 128 characters.